# Загрузка файла JSON с сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

Значения в массив подгружаются с сервера, из файла формата JSON. При помощи функции приведенной ниже. На деле же все работает не очень быстро. Как я могу оптимизировать свою функцию?

```js
data = "{"Id": 0, "Name": "Иван"},{"Id": 1,"Name": "Петр"}"

$(doc).ready(function () {
 var jsonLoad = "URL";
    $.getJSON(jsonLoad, function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
          arrName[i] = data[i].name;
    });  
});
```

Количество позиций в data = 1000, чтобы каждый раз не обращаться к серверу и по одному значению не просить, решил что будет логично сразу их закинуть в массив за один заход, а потом уже с массивом работать. После записи в массив значения выводятся как список, как раз на этом этапе и замечаю, что происходит заметная глаза загрузка - то есть медленная для меня.

Comment: "не очень быстро" - понятие субъективное. Сколько, например, `i` в `data`? это массив? почему не `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)`?

Comment: @igor Поправил вопрос

Comment: так может быть дело в том, как создаются 1000 DOM элементов. Стоило бы уже добавить в вопрос и этот код.

Comment: 1000 это много для любого ui, массив надо брать из бд и отдавать постранично по 20-100 записей

Comment: Вам нужна постраничная навигация и `LIMIT` в бд. Это не будет нагружать бд сервер и страницу вывода информации.

Comment: файл то шустро у вас грузится. долго могут потом отрисовываться добавленные элементы на странице. можно как уже выше написали, либо грузить и показывать маленькими частями, либо загрузить все сразу и потом показывать маленькими частями. Если модель поведения пользователя не предусматривает просмотр всех данных, то и смысла грузить  все сразу, наверное, нет.

Comment: У васв примере data - это не валидный JSON

Answer (score 0):

> Как идея может лучше строить такой большой массив на стороне сервера
>   сразу, а не делать запрос на тысячу записей на стороне клиента.

Но если так не позволяют обстоятельства, то можно использовать метод **setTimeout** *(в теории)* он вызовет *асинхронное* событие и при этом должен уменьшить нагрузку(проверил у себя на сайте). Как вариант создай прогресс бар, что бы показать что идет загрузка.

```
 var getMyJson = function(){
    var data = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (var i in response.links){
            setTimeout(showInConsole, 0,response.links[i]) 
          }
      }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "https://reddit-x-tymchenko.c9users.io/api/v1/links");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "66bb89a6-b62e-ea00-fc00-0957c538193b");

    xhr.send(data);
  } 
  var showInConsole = function(obj){
    console.log(obj.title)
  }
getMyJson();
```

Comment: setTimeout не создает отдельного потока. Даже в теории!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ошибка. нужно было написать _асинхронным_.

Comment: Ну так исправьте. Кстати, у вас еще и ошибка в вызове setTimeout: вы первым аргументом туда `undefined` передаете...

Comment: @PavelMayorov почему `undefined`? Я же передаю туда метод.. `setTimeout(showInConsole(response.links[i]), 0)`

Comment: А вы подмените setTimeout да проверьте: `function setTimeout(x, y) { console.log("setTimeout", x, y); }`. Или так внимательно посмотрите что именно вы туды передаете.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я понял о чем ты. Я не правильно передавал аргумент в метод, странно что он корректно работал =(